# How do I swap two nodes with their content in a singly linked list?

Tags: java, linked-list, swap, singly-linked-list

I googled this, but all of them are talking "swap nodes without swapping data".

I tried to write a swap node method myself:

```
public void swapNodes(int num1, int num2) {

    if(num1 == num2) {
        return;
    }

    Node currentNum1 = head;
    Node currentNum2 = head;
    Node waitForSwap1 = null;
    Node waitForSwap2 = null;
    while (currentNum1 != null) {
        if (currentNum1.data == num1) {
            waitForSwap1 = currentNum1;
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("waitForSwap 1");
            System.out.println(waitForSwap1.data);

        }
        currentNum1 = currentNum1.next;
    }

    while (currentNum2 != null) {
        if (currentNum2.data == num2) {
            waitForSwap2 = currentNum2;
            System.out.println("waitForSwap 2");
            System.out.println(waitForSwap2.data);

        }
        currentNum2 = currentNum2.next;
    }

    currentNum1 = waitForSwap2;
    currentNum2 = waitForSwap1;

    System.out.println("currentNum1");
    System.out.println(currentNum1.data);

    System.out.println("currentNum2");
    System.out.println(currentNum2.data);
}
```

Here's the result
[image]

As you can see, `currentNum1` and `currentNum2` changed to each other, but the printed result is not swapped. How do I swap two nodes and their data?

Edit: the complete example below

**Node Class**

```
public class Node {

public int data;
public Node next;

public Node(int _data) {
    this.data = _data;
    this.next = null;
}

public String toString() {
    return (Integer.toString(data));
}
}
```

**Linked List Class**

```
public class LinkedList {

Node head;

public void Insert(int data) {
    Node node = new Node(data);

    if (head == null) {
        head = node;
    } else {
        Node n = head;
        while (n.next != null) {
            n = n.next;
        }
        n.next = node;
    }
}

public void ShowList() {
    Node node = head;
    while (node != null) {
        System.out.print(node.data + " ");
        node = node.next;
    }
}

public void swapNodes(int num1, int num2) {

    if (num1 == num2) {
        return;
    }

    Node currentNum1 = head;
    Node currentNum2 = head;
    Node waitForSwap1 = null;
    Node waitForSwap2 = null;
    while (currentNum1 != null) {
        if (currentNum1.data == num1) {
            waitForSwap1 = currentNum1;
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("waitForSwap 1");
            System.out.println(waitForSwap1.data);

        }
        currentNum1 = currentNum1.next;
    }

    while (currentNum2 != null) {
        if (currentNum2.data == num2) {
            waitForSwap2 = currentNum2;
            System.out.println("waitForSwap 2");
            System.out.println(waitForSwap2.data);

        }
        currentNum2 = currentNum2.next;
    }

    currentNum1 = waitForSwap2;
    currentNum2 = waitForSwap1;

    System.out.println("currentNum1");
    System.out.println(currentNum1.data);

    System.out.println("currentNum2");
    System.out.println(currentNum2.data);
}
}
```

**Tester**

```
public class Runner {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    LinkedList lkdList = new LinkedList();

    lkdList.Insert(10);
    lkdList.Insert(9);
    lkdList.Insert(15);
    lkdList.Insert(2);
    lkdList.Insert(73);

    lkdList.ShowList();

    lkdList.swapNodes(10, 2);

    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("After Swap");

    lkdList.ShowList();
}

}
```

Comment: Please, come up with [mcve], so we can simply copy paste your code and debug. Also, why "swap nodes without swapping data" doesn't work for you?

Comment: You are actually not swaping the node, you are just assigning the found nodes to Node object and printing their values. In order to swap, you also need to track previous node, because to swap you will change the value of previous.next as well.

Comment: You aren't changing anything structurally in your list; you only change what your local variables refer to.

Comment: @SergeiSirik It's the requirement of the assignment, the professor want us to change both nodes and data.

Comment: So, if I get it right, it is exactly what you are looking for "swap nodes without swapping data" - it means that nodes objects will be swapped, or you have  2 different assignments: 1. swap nodes; 2 swap data in nodes without swapping nodes?

Comment: @SergeiSirik you are right. Now I 've thought this through, I think I have an idea how to do it. How do I mark an unanswered question as complete? Should I just delete it?

Comment: You can just accept some answer, or provide your answer and accept it. You are not supposed to delete the question, the main idea of stackoverflow is to be a knowledge base, so in the future if somebody has the same question he can simply search and find it answered already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, if you only want to swap data, not nodes, here it is:

```
  public void swapNodes(int num1, int num2) {

    if (num1 == num2) {
      return;
    }

    Node node1 = null;
    Node node2 = null;

    Node cur = head;
    while(cur != null) {
      if (num1 == cur.data) {
        node1 = cur;
      }
      if (num2 == cur.data) {
        node2 = cur;
      }
      cur = cur.next;
    }

    if (node1 == null || node2 == null)
      return;

    int tmp = node1.data;
    node1.data = node2.data;
    node2.data = tmp;
  }
```